# Why are JetpackCompose dependencies now appendending libs.X in build.gradle.kts?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm new to Android development, i'm also paranoid by nature and **I've noticed my dependencies have changed recently when building a new jetpack compose (empty activity) project.** I tried looking up the Google Android documentation and cannot find any mention of this.

> Can someone explain to me why the dependency package has
> implementation(**libs**.androidx...) appended onto it?

My android studio version has also upgraded to **Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1**

Assuming it's not malicious, I'm guessing it's a change in declaring dependencies? Where do I change or check the versions then? How do I keep specific versions now? Some clarity on what I'm looking at would be greatly appreciated.

here are the newest dependencies build.gradle.kts file

```
dependencies {

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.graphics)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.androidx.material3)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.junit4)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest)
}
```

to give some context, this is the previous build.gradle.kts files from about 1 month ago.

```
dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.0")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found my answer. It was in this guide:
[Migrate your build to version catalogs](https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-catalogs)

I'm guessing the Android studio update just auto generates a version catalog now.